# В чем разница методов тестирования assertThat() и assertTrue()?

Tags: android, junit

Вот есть 2 метода

```
assertThat(EmailValidator.isValidEmail("name@email.com"), is(true));
```

и

```
assertTrue(EmailValidator.isValidEmail("name@email.com"));
```

В чем их разница? Я так понимаю они делают одно и тоже...

Когда нужно использовать один и когда другой?

Comment: В том, что именно вы таким образом утверждаете. В первом случае у вас абстрактное утверждение, и фреймворк выдаст текстовое сообщение "утверждение провалилось", во втором случае он просто скажет "false не был равен true, как ожидалось". Разница действительно довольно тонкая.

Comment: @Etki  я вижу что в случае с `assertThat` в логе пишется более внятная информация... Лучше где возможно использовать этот метод мне так думается...

Comment: Да, assertTrue нужен в тех случаях, когда на расписывание тестов нет времени и когда проверяется какой-то булев метод (e.g. payload.isValid())

Comment: @Etki вы написали, что когда нет времени, значит в идеале все же нужно стремиться к тому, чтоб использовать `assertTrue(), assertFalse() и т.д.` ?

Comment: Нет, я просто вспоминаю тот пример с assert X is instance of Y. Там нет ничего страшного в том, чтобы вызвать `assertTrue(x instanceof Y)`, что сэкономит время на мелком проекте, но при грамотном написании тестов там должен быть `assertThat(x, <нужный матчер>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя `assertTrue`, Вы говорите, что переменную вы сравниваете c `true`. А `assertThat` вы можете сравнивать не только с `true`. например вот `assertThat(x, is(3))` - вы проверяете, что х это 3. И сюда не применима соответственно `assertTrue`

Comment: я так понимаю что такой подход более гибкий что ли... Но ведь в случае с числами мы так же можем использовать `assertEquals()` ... получается `assertThat()` заменяет все это разнообразие `true, false, equals` одним методом

Comment: Вот ссылка на документацию http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/ReleaseNotes4.4.html. там описаны преимущества такого `assertThat()`